# exclude specific objectIDs from being retrieved in Algolia

Tags: php, algolia

I am trying to exclude some objectIDs from being retrieved in the query time. I have tried many approaches:

`NOT objectID: 123` tried this in Algolia dashboard and not working.

`objectID :- 123` tried this in Algolia dashboard and working but not in the code, using php client.

If possible how to do for multiple objectIDs?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it possible and even for multiple objectIDs.

The right syntax for [the PHP API client](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/php/parameters/#filters) is:

```
$client = new \AlgoliaSearch\Client('APP_ID', 'API_KEY');
$index = $client->initIndex('index_name');

$results = $index->search('query', ['filters' => 'NOT objectID:XX AND NOT objectID:YY']);
```

If you want to do the same in JS with using pure API client you can do it like:

```
var client = algoliasearch('APP_ID', 'API_KEY');
var index = client.initIndex('index_name');

index.search('', { filters: 'NOT objectID:XX'}, function(err, content) {
    console.log(content.nbHits);
});
```